# Page url not changing in flutter, but the page content changes fine

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Hi I am trying to implement a page in flutter web that takes an id from the url and shows data according to that id. It's working in the sense that the page gets the data, but the url itself is not changing in the browser.

For the routes section I have put this

```
                      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
                        List<String> routeSplit = settings.name.split('/');
                        if (routeSplit[1] == 'pdp' && routeSplit.length > 2) {
                          int pdpId = int.parse(routeSplit[2]);
                          return MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  ActivityDescriptionPage(id: pdpId));
                        }
                      },
```

From this the page gets the id. And to send to the page from the code I use this:

```
onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/pdp/' + activityId.toString())
```

So when i execute the above line from say `/products` page, the new page content is loaded but the url in the browser remains `/products` only. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just add `settings: settings,` to `MaterialPageRoute`

Comment: This is correct, even when you aren't using Material, you can pass `settings` to `PageRouteBuilder` for example.

Comment: is it possible to update the url inside of a statefull widget without using the `Navigator`?

Answer (score 6):

Pass the settings in MaterialPageRoute.
Like this,

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
  List<String> routeSplit = settings.name.split('/');
  if (routeSplit[1] == 'pdp' && routeSplit.length > 2) {
    int pdpId = int.parse(routeSplit[2]);
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      settings: settings,
      builder: (context) => ActivityDescriptionPage(id: pdpId)
    );
  }
},
```

It will change the page content & the URL as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had to pass the settings object to the Material Page route.
I found it here, there's an example there as well.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53361#issuecomment-607521191

Comment: Please provide source code, not just link.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have 
some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the 
target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: **Other reviewers: I haven't flagged this answer**