# Url path not changing when navigating back to previous page in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, web, routes

I am working on a flutter app. i have set up router in the app with named routes. on going to my home page it shows as locahost:1234/#/home. and the path is correct. but from there when a navigate back to previouse page it still showing the same path locahost:1234/#/home. the path url is not changing on navigating back. if any one has an idea?
my router file is as follows:

```
  /* ADD REPOSITORY TO APP ROUTER */
  /* ADD REPOSITORY TO APP ROUTER */
  Repository repository;
  AppRouter() {
    repository = new Repository(apiService: ApiService());
  }

  Route generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case "/":
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: RouteSettings(name: '/'),
            builder: (_) => MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
                  BlocProvider<HomeCubit>(
                    create: (BuildContext context) {
                      return HomeCubit(repository: repository);
                    },
                  ),
                  BlocProvider<SearchCubit>(
                    create: (BuildContext context) =>
                        SearchCubit(repository: repository),
                  ),
                  BlocProvider<UserCubit>(
                    create: (BuildContext context) {
                      return UserCubit(repository: repository);
                    },
                  )
                ], child:userToken==null?SplashScreen():NavScreen()
                // SplashScreen()
                ));
                case "/getstarted":
                 return MaterialPageRoute(
           settings: RouteSettings(name: '/getstarted'),
            builder: (_) => BlocProvider(
                create: (BuildContext context) =>
                    ProfileCubit(repository: repository),
                child: OnboardingScreen()));
      //return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => VideoDetailScreen());
      case "/register":
        return MaterialPageRoute(
           settings: RouteSettings(name: '/register'),
            builder: (_) => MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
                  BlocProvider<HomeCubit>(
                    create: (BuildContext context) {
                      return HomeCubit(repository: repository);
                    },
                  ),
                  BlocProvider<SearchCubit>(
                    create: (BuildContext context) =>
                        SearchCubit(repository: repository),
                  ),
                  BlocProvider<UserCubit>(
                    create: (BuildContext context) =>
                        UserCubit(repository: repository),
                  )
                ], child: RegisterScreen()));
      case '/home':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
           settings: RouteSettings(name: '/home'),
            builder: (_) => BlocProvider(
                create: (BuildContext context) =>
                    HomeCubit(repository: repository),
                child: NavScreen()));
      case '/signin':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => BlocProvider(
                create: (BuildContext context) =>
                    UserCubit(repository: repository),
                child: SigninScreen()),
                 settings: RouteSettings(name: '/signin'));
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text('Error! No route Found...',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight:FontWeight.bold),),
            ),
          );
        }
        );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: make sure you use Navigator.push() and not  Navigator.pushReplacement()

Comment: i use navigator.pushreplacement for new routes. but during the pop the path is not changing,

Comment: You have to implement Flutter's Navigator 2.0 in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

```
Just add settings: settings, to MaterialPageRoute
```

[Page url not changing in flutter, but the page content changes fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66182115/6185804)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Are you saying that this is a duplicate question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void main() {
  GoRouter.optionURLReflectsImperativeAPIs = true;
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Flutter Navigator 2.0 to achieve Dynamic and Deep linking i.e Changing URLs on page change and getting the functionality of Browser's back and reload button.

The easiest way to achieve this is by using [go_router](https://gorouter.dev/) Flutter package, which has very easy setup and documentation.

In this you can define your paths which changes on page change.